# after installing resharper 6 VS takes too much CPU time

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, resharper-6.0

I've upgraded Resharper from 5 version to 6 version.
After that when I type something inside VS I do see "lags".
I.e. text doesn't appear immediatly after key pressed.
My CPU is pretty slow - it's Pentium U5400
However with Resharper 5 i didn't seen such lags. I was working pretty comfortable. Now I see lags. Is it because CPU is too slow or this is Resharper bug?

If Resharper 6 has new features which require CPU time while i'm typing (anything, even comments)? It lags always.

While I type comment in VS "devenv.exe" process takes 70% of CPU. I will test how Resharper 6 works on my desktop (i7-860) in a moment.

The question is why Resharper 6 takes much more CPU than Resharper 5 and what nice features I have for that?

**upd** on i7-860 while typing VS takes 10% of CPU what ~ 70% of U5400. So the question is elligable. why Resharper 6 takes much more CPU than Resharper 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use ReSharper 6.1.1? If not, then you should, because it contains many performance fixes. If you use ReSharper 6.1.1 and still experience lags, try to disable other Visual Studio extensions and plugins. If there is no extensions and plugins other that ReSharper 6.1.1 and typing is still slow, then please make a performance snapshot and send it to JetBrains as described here [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+Profiling+Instructions). Also you can try to disable ReSharper's typing assists features (go to ReSharper | Options -> Environment | Editor and disable all Auto- and Highlight options, repeat at ReSharper | Options -> Code Editing | HTML/ASP.NET/Razor | Editor).